# How to correctly configure a spring resource server?

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have two spring application, one as backend service and one as frontend service. Users can log in into the front end service using keycloak SSO. This is working fine. The frontend then request data from the backend per REST interface. The backend application is configured as resource server and the frontend uses a rest template with interceptor to send requests to the backend. The interceptor adds the current access token to the request header. My problem now is that the backend always responds with a token invalid error.

I followed the spring documentation to setup the resource server (backend application).

Backend Application

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resource:
        user-info-uri: http://my-user-info.uri
```

Using postman, I get the correct user infos from my user-info-uri when I put the token the frontend is using in the request header. What else do I need to correctly configure my backend application?

Answer (score 0):

For whom it is of any interest:

The trick is in the application.yml. I simply removed the spring identifier (i.e., security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri instead of spring.security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri) and everything worked fine.